# Stuck on startup screen

Tags: windows-8.1

When I start up my Windows 8.1 PC, it says "Diagnosing PC" and then enters the Automatic Repair loading screen. I decided to leave it on all night long and when I woke up I checked it and it was still doing the same thing. I turned it off then back on and it did the same thing, but this time Windows had the options to restart or troubleshoot problems. I tried doing everything in the troubleshooting menu but nothing worked.

Comment: I assume you've tried System Restore.  Did it give any sort of error message?

Comment: Here are two links to articles that contain possible solutions to the problem. Please indicate if one has worked for you. [article 1](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/139576-startup-repair-infinite-loop-recovery.html) and [article 2](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_update/how-to-fix-the-automatic-repair-loop-in-windows-81/bfc92bc7-031f-45d4-b623-bcb4847d32fd).

Comment: @harrymc I am trying article 2 solution 3, but I haven't  gotten a result since it takes hours. I went with article 2, because its for windows 8.1. The other one is for windows 7

Comment: @DominatorX I actually cant do a system restore, because I don't have the windows cd, and it asks for it

Comment: Article 1 might still apply to Windows 8.1, although I cannot be sure about it. For getting a Windows 8.1 boot cd, see [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), using another computer.

Comment: You might want to try a SFC scan from command prompt (`sfc /scannow`). The scan can take up to 1 hour, but it looks for corrupt system files and tries to repair them. More details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833.

Comment: @DominatorX I'll try that after I finish trying to do another solution thats also scanning... LOL so many solutions

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like windows is seriously corrupted, it's missing quite a few essential files to  be that broken. Have you tried booting it in safe mode?

You can do this by holding the "shift key" mashing F8 or F12 or "esc"  respectfully of the pc.

You can find out more here
http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/

Also, do you have GRUB or 3rd party boot managers, or any mods at all to your default system. Can you also recall what's the last thing you did before this happened? Any thing you installed recently?

SOLUTION?(in reply to the previous comment but ran out of space)

that's properly the root of your issues. If it's a custom built PC get the  installation CD that came with the graphics card and reinstall the drivers from there. And if windows asks you to update just reject it.

you can also just rip out the graphics card and see if windows falls back to integrated graphics.  and if it boot then you have found your problem. from there you can find lots of guides on the internet to revert to your default graphical drivers.

also if you don't mind you can use win8s built in "refresh" mode. This will delete all  the programs (including the drivers) but keep your files intact. But this is only if you can get to that, I'm not sure of the current situation but if you can get into troubleshooting menu you can probabilist get into this as well.

finally, if all else fails try booting into a linux live CD/USB, and if it boots then it's a 97% drivers/windows issue. but if it also doesn’t then something on your pc is broken physically :(

Comment: I have tried booting it in safe mode, but it just goes back to the startup screen. I have left it on all day after putting it in safe mode but it does nothing. No I don't think I do have any GRUB or 3rd party boot managers (or that I know of). The last thing I did that it started doing this problem was that I installed a new graphics driver

Comment: @Universeking222 check what i added to my original post

Comment: I can change to my cpu's graphics card, which I have done, but still doesnt work. What I am going to do is to just wipe my computer once I get the windows disk.

Comment: sound like you screwed up pretty big :p
but at least you know it's a windows problem and nothing to do with your hardware